# How to upload using CarrierWave an http_basic_authentication protected file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, basic-authentication

I'm trying to upload a file that is protected under http_basic_authentication with CarrierWave. Here is the tested code:

```
hs = House.new
hs.remote_house_url = "http://username:password@127.0.0.1:3000/houses/export.csv"
hs.save!
```

I'm expecting the file to be uploaded, but I get the following:

```
  (13.2ms)  BEGIN
  (0.8ms)   ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: The validation failed : House could not download file: userinfo not supported.  [RFC3986]
from /Users/htaidirt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
```

I know it's a problem with giving http_basic_authentication credentials (username & password) thanks to the message `http_basic_authentication`. But what is the right way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered a similar problem. OpenURI does not allow you to supply basic auth credentials as part of the url, instead it should be like

```
open("http://www.your-website.net", 
  http_basic_authentication: ["user", "password"])
```

(which I found here: http://blog.andreamostosi.name/2013/04/open-uri-and-basic-authentication/)

Carrierwave does not seem to support this by default. For now, I have monkey patched the CarrierWave::Uploader::Download::RemoteFile class to add the required basic auth. I will try and submit a better version of this as a pull request so hopefully it can be added to the gem, but for now I created config/initializers/overrides.rb with the contents:

```
#add basic auth to carrierwave
module CarrierWave
  module Uploader
    module Download
      class RemoteFile
        private
        def file
          if @file.blank?
            @file = Kernel.open(@uri.to_s, http_basic_authentication: ["USERNAME", "PASSWORD])
            @file = @file.is_a?(String) ? StringIO.new(@file) : @file
          end
          @file

        rescue Exception => e
          raise CarrierWave::DownloadError, "could not download file: #{e.message}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```